Bound state of highly idealized electron hamiltonian in hydrogen molecule ion
Consider the highly idealized electron Hamiltonian: $H=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m} \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}} -g\delta(x-x0)-g\delta(x+x0)$, where the $\pm x0$ are the positions of protons. Then the Schrödinger equation can be written as $\frac{d^{2}\Phi}{dx^{2}} +\beta(\delta(x-x0)+\delta(x+x0)) \Phi = k^{2} \Phi$, where $\beta=\frac{2mg}{\hbar^{2}}$ and $k^{2}=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^{2}}.$ Then, by proposing the solutions with odd and even parities, and solving the transcendental equations in two different cases, $\beta x0<<1$ and $\beta x0>>1,$ we get the bound state energies for the even and odd solutions in these two different cases. Why, in the case $\beta x0>>1$ (the protons are far away), the bound energy for odd parity obtained by following the above steps $(E=-\frac{\hbar^{2} \beta^{2}}{8m}(1- \exp(-\beta x0)^{2})$ is not a real bound state, is said to be because the bound state energy above decreases as x0 increases, even before we consider the repulsive force between the protons. Thus the system is unstable and the state is not a bound state. Why do we need to consider this? Isn't the bound state requirement inserted in the wavefunction? And we do get a solution.

why aren't the delta functions aligned on the $z$-axis?

You need to distinguish the electron bound state and the molecule bound state. The two are related by the Born-Oppenheimer approximation. You focused on the former, but the result you are quoting refers to the latter which is what is interesting chemically.
I will begin by making things dimensionless. I will consider the 1D system:
$$
H = -\frac12p^2-\delta(x-a/2)-\delta(x+a/2)
$$
The eigenstates have energy:
$$
E = -\frac{\kappa^2}2
$$
with $\kappa$ the imaginary wavenumber. It must be positive for a bound state (for normalisation) since it decays at infinity as:
$$
\psi\sim e^{-\kappa |x|}
$$
For even bound states, the transcendental equation is:
$$
2 = \kappa(1+\tanh(\kappa a/2))
$$
which always has a unique positive root for $a>0$. You can check the consistency in the limit case $a\to0$ where the atoms are essentially overlapping:
$$
\kappa\to 2
$$
and the case $g\to\infty$ where the atoms are far apart:
$$
\kappa\to 1
$$
For odd bound states, the equation is rather:
$$
2 = \kappa(1+\coth(\kappa a/2))
$$
You now have two regimes:

$a>1$: Just as the even case, you have exactly one bound state. This includes the infinitely spaced out limit $a\to\infty$.
$a\leq1$: Unlike the even case, you now have no bound state. This includes the overlapping limit $a\to0$. This is constant as in this limit, there is no odd bound state. The math shows that the extra bound state disappears exactly at $a=1$ (like a phase transition).

For $a<1$, your odd energy eigenvalue is therefore real and negative, but the eigenfunction is not normalisable. It is therefore a resonance rather than a bond state. However, for $a>1/2$ you have a legitimate bound state.
This was only for the electron binding the $H_2^+$ molecule. What you are rather more interested in is the binding of the two hydrogens. The usual approach is the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, and the previous discussion was the first step for computing the effective potential mediated by the electron. You can now study the spatial dependence of this potential.
For the odd state, your asymptotic formula shows that the potential behaves as:
$$
\kappa \sim 1-e^{-a} \\
E \sim -1+e^{-a}
$$
$E$ therefore decreases with distance, so the force is repulsive at long distance:
$$
F \sim e^{-a}
$$
In fact, by studying the transcendental equation, the negativity of $F$ holds at any distance, so the odd state is always repulsive that is why you call it anti-bonding. According to the previous calculation, it is not even defined for $a<1$. In fact as $a\to1^+$, you get the following asymptotics:
$$
\kappa \sim 2(a-1) \\
E \sim -2(a-1)^2 \\
F \sim 4(a-1)
$$
This is to be contrasted with the even eigenstates for which in the large distance limit $a\to\infty$:
$$
\kappa =1+e^{-a} \\
E =-1-e^{-a} \\
F \sim -e^{-a}
$$
which is attracting hence bonding. Similarly, by studying the transcendental equation, you can check that the force is always attractive, and you can also figure out the close distance asymptotics:
$$
\kappa = 2-2a \\
E = -2+4a \\
F \sim -2a
$$
Physically, you interpret it by saying that $H_2^+$ is stable, but if you excite it the molecule would break apart. Neglecting the interaction between electrons and taking into account spin, you can similarly study the stability of $H_2$ with its excited states.

The fact that the energy increases as the atoms are brought closer together tells you that the atoms are repelling each other. So while it may be a bound state of the electrons it is not a bound state of the molecule. It is instead typing to form two isolated atoms
